# Getting error while connection to Ibm_db2 from a Node js platform

Tags: node.js, npm, db2, node-modules

I am trying to connect to a DB2 server but I am getting bellow given error.

I'm following the given documentation: [npm db2 Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm_db)

I have done `npm i ibm_db2`

Code:

```
const ibmdb = require('ibm_db');

const connectQuery =
'DATABASE=' +
DATABASE +
';HOSTNAME=' +
HOSTNAME +
';UID=' +
UID +
';PWD=' +
PWD +
';PORT=' +
PORT +
';PROTOCOL=TCPIP';

ibmdb.open(connectQuery, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    conn.query('select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1', function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log('err');
        else console.log('data');

        conn.close(function() {
            console.log('done');
        });
   });
});
```

Error:

```
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → ...\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.node
 → ...\node_modules\ibm_db\build\Debug\odbc_bindings.node
 → ...\node_modules\ibm_db\build\Release\odbc_bindings.node
 → ...\node_modules\ibm_db\out\Debug\odbc_bindings.node
 → ...\node_modules\ibm_db\Debug\odbc_bindings.node
```

- Is there any other node package to establish connection ?

Comment: What platform are you on? Any errors during install?

Comment: @data_henrik Node js, there was a timeout error in downloading the driver link, but installation was successful.

Comment: The Node.js driver downloads and installs ODBC as base. I would recommend to reinstall the driver.

Comment: @data_henrik tried uninstall, clear, re-install. Getting the same error mentioned above. ODBC fails to download all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on windows 10. Because your ibm_db module is not installed successfully.

Download directly [clidriver](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ntx64_odbc_cli.zip) generated by IBM. After setting **IBM_DB_HOME** environment variable to point the directory, and reinstall ibm_db module to skip downloading clidriver.

Answer (score 0):

Because your ibm_db module is not installed successfully due to proxy on Windows 10.

You can just disconnect VPN and install ibm_db node package it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your ibm_db has conflicts. Maybe you cloned it from some repository and are trying to run it localy?

So, from your app path:

First download [clidriver](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ntx64_odbc_cli.zip) (To avoid this step on ibm_db install) and unzip it to the CLIDRIVERPATH (just any directory you would like)

Then follow those (Remove ibm_db, config IBM_DB_HOME, config LD_LIBRARY_PATHE, reinstall ibm_db).
Here are the words for it:

```
$ npm remove ibm_db

$ npm config set IBM_DB_HOME=C:\CLIDRIVERPATH\clidriver

$ npm config set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\CLIDRIVERPATH\clidriver\lib

$ npm install ibm_db
```